# Backtrack mp3 problem

Tags: ubuntu, audio, backtrack, mp3

I've installed Backtrack but I can't figure out how to play mp3files. I've installed ubuntu-restricted-extras,lame, libmp3lame but still won't work(I have Rhythmbox player, I've also tried Amarok). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install gstreamer libraries, take a [look at this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/MP3)

Use `apt-cache search gstreamer-0.10` to find related libs, and install them with `apt-get install XX`